# using ffmpeg to record highest resolution offered by Facetime cameras (mac)

Tags: ffmpeg, avfoundation

I am using the following code successfully to record a video feed from my mac

```
./ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 30  -i "default" out.mp4
```

This however seems to be recording video at the lowest resolution of `320x200`

My camera supports the following resolutions:

```
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff7b2800000] Supported modes:
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff7b2800000]   1280x720@[1.000000 30.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff7b2800000]   640x480@[1.000000 30.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff7b2800000]   320x240@[1.000000 30.000000]fps
```

I tried manually specifying the resolution using both `-s` and `-video_size` but that seems to just scale up the low res video.

How do I get ffmpeg to pick my `1280x720` resolution?

thanks

Comment: Hi, any lights on this?

Answer (score 1):

This command works for me with ffmpeg 4.0 from Homebrew:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -r 30 -s "1280x720" -i "0" out.mp4
```

The -r and -s options must come before the -i option.

It is possible to add another `-r` and/or `-s` option after `-i "0"` to change the frame rate or size of the output.

Comment: The [avfoundation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#avfoundation) options are named `-framerate` and `-video_size`.